# Unable to change title and unable to show icons on action bar

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, android-studio

I hope everyone is doing well. This is my first question on this useful website. I'm trying to create my first app on android using Android Studio (version 2.2.2). I can't seem to change the title or show the icons I have for my options menu. The following images is what it looks like.

The following are my strings.xml (some are not used):

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Weekly Duties</string>
<string name="weekly">Weekly things to do</string>
<string name="vognormal">Vault of Glass (Normal)</string>
<string name="stop">Stop Clicking me</string>
<string name="title_search">Search</string>
<string name="title_share">Share</string>

</resources>
```

This code is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/app_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="hobbiapps.destinyweeklytracker.MainActivity"
android:showAsAction="always"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/weekly"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="@string/vognormal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    tools:ignore="UnknownId" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item
    android:id="@+id/settings_id"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" //icon for settings
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_id"
    android:title="Share"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp" //icon for sharing
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_me_id"
    android:title="About Me"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/Contact_Me_id"
    android:title="Contact Me"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_id"
    android:title="Search"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/> //icon for searching


</menu>
```

And last but not least the MainActivity.java

```
package hobbiapps.destinyweeklytracker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuinflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuinflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks you for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Are you using a custom toolbar? If not thats what I would suggest doing first, adding a custom toolbar. Its easy,

1. create a toolbar.xml layout
2. putting something like what follows as the xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar         
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```

then you want to add these lines of code to every page that uses the toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.(YOUR STRING);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.(YOUR LOGO);
```

and also
in your XML for the activity

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/seekrToolbar"/>
```

then back in the code for the activity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

then to select items

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings_id) {

    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share_id) {

    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about_me_id) {

    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.contact_me_id) {

    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search_id) {

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```